# Keyboard shortcut to hide/show all tool windows except the editor in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

When I doubleclick an editor tab in PhpStorm 2016.3.2, all tool windows are hidden, **including the Project view**. When I doubleclick the tab again, the previously open tool windows reappear. Very nifty for quickly utilizing 95% of my 13" laptop display (I should add that I don't really like the `Distraction free mode` since it is slower and also hides line numbers and other stuff).

Since I prefer working with keyboard shortcuts, I would like to have one that does the same thing, without having to click anything. I tried the `Hide active tool window` setting, and it's close but no cigar - it doesn't hide the `Project view`, only the bottom tool window.

Anyone know of any menu commands that mimic the "doubleclick on an editor tab"?

Comment: `Window | Active Tool Window | Hide All Windows` (`Ctrl+Shift+F12`) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Window | Active Tool Window | Hide All Windows` (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F12</kbd>  using Default keymap)